# Swagger unexpected API PATCH action documentation of JsonPatchDocument in example request body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm making a Core 3.1 web API and using [JsonPatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to create a PATCH action. I have an action named `Patch` which has a `JsonPatchDocument` parameter. Here is the action's signature:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public ActionResult<FileRecordDto> Patch(int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<FileRecordQueryParams> patchDoc)
```

As I understand, the parameter needs to receive JSON data in the following structure, which I've successfully tested with the action:

```
[
  {
    "op": "operationName",
    "path": "/propertyName",
    "value": "newPropertyValue"
  }
]
```

However, the action's documentation generated by [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) has a different structure:
[image]

I'm not familiar with this structure and even `"value"` property is missing from it, which a `JsonPatchDocument` object has. Every example of patching with the `replace` operation I've seen has had the first structure.

Why is Swagger generating an alternate structure for a `JsonPatchDocument` object in the request body for the PATCH endpoint? How do I fix this?

The NuGet package installed for Swagger:
[image: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v5.6.3]

Comment: What version of swagger? There are multiple standards

Comment: Here's the [latest speciation (v 3.0.3)](https://swagger.io/specification/). It's not clear from the question what this JSON is supposed to represent so it's hard to be specific

Comment: Thanks. I have the NuGet package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v5.6.3 installed to get Swagger tools, though I'm not sure if its version is separate from Swaggers, or if it's even a separate thing altogether.

Comment: I've updated the question to show a picture of what the JSON is supposed to represent.

Comment: and whats `JsonPatchDocument<FileRecordQueryParams> `?

Comment: It's ASP.NET Core's implementation of handling JSON Patch requests. `FileRecordQueryParams` is the parameter constraint for `JsonPatchDocument<T>` and then I can use methods like `.ApplyTo()` to actually do the patching.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` doesn't work propertly with this type `JsonPatchDocument<UpdateModel>`, which doesn’t represent the expected patch request doument.

You need to custome a document filter to modify the generated specification.

```
public class JsonPatchDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var schemas = swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.ToList();
        foreach (var item in schemas)
        {
            if (item.Key.StartsWith("Operation") || item.Key.StartsWith("JsonPatchDocument"))
                swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove(item.Key);
        }

        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Add("Operation", new OpenApiSchema
        {
            Type = "object",
            Properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>
            {
                {"op", new OpenApiSchema{ Type = "string" } },
                {"value", new OpenApiSchema{ Type = "string"} },
                {"path", new OpenApiSchema{ Type = "string" } }
            }
        });

        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Add("JsonPatchDocument", new OpenApiSchema
        {
            Type = "array",
            Items = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.Schema, Id = "Operation" }
            },
            Description = "Array of operations to perform"
        });

        foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths.SelectMany(p => p.Value.Operations)
        .Where(p => p.Key == Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OperationType.Patch))
        {
            foreach (var item in path.Value.RequestBody.Content.Where(c => c.Key != "application/json-patch+json"))
                path.Value.RequestBody.Content.Remove(item.Key);
            var response = path.Value.RequestBody.Content.Single(c => c.Key == "application/json-patch+json");
            response.Value.Schema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.Schema, Id = "JsonPatchDocument" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Register the filter:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.DocumentFilter<JsonPatchDocumentFilter>());
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, although I did need to add in some lines to remove unused schemas

Comment: Can this be made to work if the JsonPatchDocument<T> is itself within a class that's being bound? My PatchDocument is a property of a Command dto which includes the id from the route and the document from the body of the request. This filter isn't working as-is.

Comment: @ssmith Did you find a solution? We have the exact same problem.

Comment: I think I got it working - not 100% sure. The repo is here; https://github.com/ardalis/WebApiBestPractices/blob/main/api_templates/ApiBestPractices.Endpoints/Endpoints/Authors/Patch.cs you can clone it and see if it's behaving the way you need.